# Как узнать координаты точки, в которую ткнул пользователь? C#

Tags: c#

Мне нужно узнать координаты точки, на которую нажал пользователь на форме.

Comment: А нет ли у формы каких-нибудь событий?

Comment: На форму невесте событие onclick и в нем передается e. В нем есть что вам нужно

Comment: И что за форма? WinForms, WPF?..

Comment: Streletz, WinForms.

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, спасибо, только не onclick а MouseClick.